# Vim 8.0 mystery: `:r!` command in `:au BufRead` handler causing unwanted side effects

Tags: vim

I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
:function GitCommitMsg()
:  set tw=62
:  if getline(1) == ""
:    1 
:    r!git diff -w --minimal --cached
:    1d
:  endif
:  set syntax=diff
:endf 
:au BufRead,BufNewFile COMMIT_EDITMSG call GitCommitMsg()
```

For years, the above has worked fine with Vim 7.x, but has started to misbehave under Vim 8 on Ubuntu 18.

The interior of the `if` statement is executed for new commits. The idea is to supply some content when making a new commit, but otherwise leave the message alone.

When that interior executes, then neither the `set tw=62` nor the `set syntax=diff` take effect. The observed values are `72` and `gitcommit`, respectively.

Somehow, the conditional `:r!` invocation is causing the issue. If we comment it out:

```
:function GitCommitMsg()
:  set tw=62
:  if getline(1) == ""
:    1 
":    r!git diff -w --minimal --cached
:    1d
:  endif
:  set syntax=diff
:endf 
:au BufRead,BufNewFile COMMIT_EDITMSG call GitCommitMsg()
```

then `set tw=62` and `set syntax=diff` take effect in all cases.

Note that the `:r!git diff` does work: the output of `git diff ...` is loaded into the buffer, and the leading empty line is deleted by `1d`.

The cause isn't specifically `git diff` or the content it produces; the problem persists regardless of what command's output we read with `:r!`.  So, for instance, this still has the problem:

```
:function GitCommitMsg()
:  set tw=62
:  if getline(1) == ""
:    1 
:    r!echo foo
:    1d
:  endif
:  set syntax=diff
:endf 
:au BufRead,BufNewFile COMMIT_EDITMSG call GitCommitMsg()
```

How can we read the output of a command into the buffer in the middle of `au` processing without unwanted side effects like settings being clobbered?

Comment: I suppose that changing `BufRead,BufNewFile` to `BufWinEnter` should fix your issue.

Comment: @Matt Yes, that does; I see that basically we are delaying the the invocation of our hook to a later time.  If you make that an answer, I can accept it, but it would still be good to know why this broke. BTW, I have a few `BufWinEnter` actions, to arrange some  some globally enforced syntax highlighting, like flagging extra blanks at the ends of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply changing `BufRead,BufNewFile` to `BufWinEnter` should fix your issue.

The problem is probably due to the fact that at the time of `BufRead` only the buffer exists, but the window for it is not chosen (or even not created yet). To workaround this issue Vim makes use of some quirks, so your script may be running in the context of some temporary window (try to trace `win_getid()` value), and after that Vim will copy window-local options (such as `tw`) from "last used window" and so on.

Another point is that arbitrary Ex commands must have a window context to run (for instance, there's `win_execute()`, but there's no `buf_execute()`). Hence executing `:read` could also result in manipulating "temporaries".

Well, this probably was a speculation rather than an explanation, but I hope you got the idea.